# Android quickblox how to receive message if user is not in chat room

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, quickblox

I am working on chat application using **Quickblox SDK**.

private and public chat are working fine, user successfully receives the message from a group and in one to one chat.

My problem is where I am showing all the friends and groups list that the user has joined. I want to show a notification if user received any message from group or from private chat (the user has not opened any chat room).

Push notification messages are not being received in this screen, they are only received when I close the app or logout. Is there any way in **Quickblox** to show message notification if user is not in chat room but logged in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For private group chats push notifications will be sent if you are not in a room (didn't join).

Another way is to join all your rooms at start app, then you will be able to receive all messages from any group chat in a realtime

Comment: can you please share some code how we can join all chat room private and groups?

Comment: This page contains all needed information http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample